# Docking windows on the left or right of the screen

Tags: skype, window-manager, window

I would like to dock my instant messenger and have it always be visible. Note: I am NOT referring to tiling. A docked window prevents any other window from maximizing over it, permanently, just like the taskbar/panel.

I am using XFCE, but I am interested in any kind of solution.

Comment: Consider using a proper [tiling window manager](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Comparison_of_tiling_window_managers), like i3 or ratpoison.

Answer (score 2):

I am still searching for a convenient method, but I found a workaround.

It is possible to use `xprop` to set the necessary properties to make any window behave like a docked panel. This worked with Slack and is compatible with most window managers.

- Reserve 300px on the right side of your screen.

  - `xprop -f _NET_WM_STRUT 32c -set _NET_WM_STRUT 0,300,0,0`
  - Click on the application's winow
- Move and resize your window into that space.
- (**Optional**) Make the window always-on-top, hide it from the taskbar, and from Alt+Tab (but it also kills keyboard input for some reason)

  - `xprop -f _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE 32a -set _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DOCK`
  - Click on the app's window

Consult the [freedesktop.org documentation](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/1.3/ar01s05.html). Perhaps there are more/better options that could be set to get a 100% correct result. I also don't know how to set these options automatically.